# How to show only first author for one bibtex entry

Tags: bibtex, author-number

How to show only first author for one particular bibtex entry? I am using scrbook if that info is of any value for this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In particular, your bibliography style is important, as well as knowing whether you use packages like `natbib`.

Comment: No MWE: sorry but as it stands this is unclear.