# Show first author only with \cite (with exceptions) - maxcitenames ignored for some authors

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

In a presentation I am currently working on, I would like to have all citations look like

> [LastNameOfFirstAuthor et al. 1999]

where 1999 is the year and the "et al."  only shows up for multiple authors.
In same cases (namely the ones where I am talking about my papers and I am not first author), I would like to have it like

> [LastNameOfFirstAuthor, LastNameOfSecondAuthor, MyLastName et al. 1999]

I tried to achive this behaviour with these settings:

```
\usepackage[url=false,citestyle=authoryear,block=ragged,backend=biber,
            maxalphanames=1,maxcitenames=1,indexing=true]{biblatex}
```

plus overriding the cite command like

```
\let\ORIGcite=\cite
\renewcommand{\cite}[2][1]{%
  \AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{#1}\defcounter{minnames}{#1}}
  \footnotesize[\ORIGcite{#2}]%
}
```

The latter part seems to be working fine, but if you have an author that is cited multiple times (with different works), the `maxcitenames` setting is ignored.

Even explicitly setting the number of authors `\cite\[1\]{...}` does not help.

Here comes a MWE (hope the formatting is not too bad)

```
\documentclass[noshadow]{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\RequirePackage[url=false,citestyle=authoryear,block=ragged,backend=biber,maxcitenames=1,indexing=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@InProceedings{b,
  Title                    = {BBB},
  Author                   = {Justin For and Compa Rison},
  Year                     = {1999}
}
@PhdThesis{a,
  Title                    = {AAA},
  Author                   = {Some Name},
  Year                     = {2002},
}
@InProceedings{c,
  Title                    = {CCC},
  Author                   = {Some Name and Second Author},
  Year                     = {2012},
}
\end{filecontents}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\section{Slide 1}
\begin{frame}
    \cite{c}\\
    \cite{b,a}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Literature}
    \printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

This produces

```
Name and Author 2012
For et al. 1999; Name 2002
```

but should produce

```
Name et al. 2012           <---
For et al. 1999; Name 2002
```

I'd appreciate any help on this question.

I guess [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119739/29082), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135471/29082) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75043/29082) are related to this one; but they didn't help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I found the solution myself. This seems to be connected to the 
`uniquelist=false` setting. More details can be found here

[Set limit to one author when using "et al." in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69028/set-limit-to-one-author-when-using-et-al-in-biblatex)

However, it seems weird to me, because in the example I gave, the keys would be unique (given the different publication year and the "et al." - where the latter might not count).

Answer (score 1):

The idea embedded in your original question helped me.  I'll extract it and clean it up a little, here:

```
\newcommand{\citefirst}[1]{%
  \AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{1}\defcounter{minnames}{1}}%
  \citet{#1}%
}
```

If you only want to cite the author, replace the `\citet` with `\citeauthor`.